# What is the difference between these sentences?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning

I'm writing a formal email to my senior and I'm confused which one should I use.

> I demonstrated you about the working of XYZ.
>
> I demonstrated about the working of XYZ to you.
>
> I demonstrated XYZ and it's working to you.

Do each of these 3 sentences give a different meaning?

Comment: I think only the third is grammatical, but may not say what you want it to say. What are you trying to communicate here?

Comment: I had demonstrated my project to him and wanted to remind him about it. I think I should go with the third one.

Comment: @Tyler: The third one isn't grammatical either. The apostrophised **it's** is simply *wrong*, and idiomatically it would almost always be pluralised **workings** as well.

Comment: @Nick_inaw: Unless you have some special reason why you think you *should* be using the verb "demonstrate" here, you'd almost certainly do better sticking to "show".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good call. I missed that. Nick, we can help a lot more if you can provide more detail about the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“The workings” refers to how something works, so “I demonstrated **the workings** of XYZ” would mean “I demonstrated **the way in which** XYZ works”.

If you are talking about the fact that something works, you will be better off saying something like “I demonstrated to you **that** XYZ **works**.”

This all assumes that you are making a specific reference to a single point in the past. If you are discussing the current state of affairs, you will want to say something like “I **have** demonstrated to you that XYZ works.”